# Angular Application on IIS - After Login

Tags: html, angular, web, iis

I'm encountering an issue with my Angular application deployed on an IIS server, and it's working as expected on my local machine. The website is configured for HTTPS. However, after being redirected from the login page to the home page, I'm unable to navigate to any other page. Additionally, all attempts to upload images on the site are failing.

I tried to remove everything in base href in the html file

[image]
I also configured web.config

[image]

Comment: After you are redirected to the homepage, do you get any error messages when you navigate to other pages? You can use the F12 developer tools to check if there are any related error messages in the console.